# Implement notifications through ajax in django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a feed stream in which users are shown activities, I have to notify users of new activity after the page is loaded through ajax call.
Below is the code

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def new_activity(request):

    context = {}
    response = {}
    latest_activity = []        
    prev_activity_id = request.GET.get('activity_id')
    #get the latest activity from news feed
    time_stamp = Activity.objects.get(pk = prev_activity_id).created
    latest_activity = Activity.objects.filter(created__gt = time_stamp)
    activity_count  = latest_activity.count()


    #Handle multiple activities
    if activity_count == 1:
        updated_id = latest_activity.id
    elif activity_count > 1:
        updated_id = latest_activity[0].id
    else:
        updated_id = prev_activity_id

    context['activities'] = latest_activity

    template = render_to_string('activities/new_activity_template.html', context,    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    response['template'] = template
    response['updated_id'] = updated_id
    response['activity_count'] = activity_count
    response['success'] = 'success'

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response), mimetype='application/json')
```

**ajax**

```
(function new_activity() {

    setTimeout(function() {
            var activity_id = null

        $.ajax({
            url: "/activities/all/new_activity/?activity_id="+activity_id,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
            $('#id_new_activity').empty();
            $('#id_new_activity').append(response.template);
                console.log(response.success);

                    //if activity_id is null get the activity id for first time
                    //if activity_id is not null update the activity_id from the response

                activity_id = response.updated_id;



            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: new_activity,
            timeout: 2000
        })
    }, 5000);
})();
```

I need to update the latest acitivity_id after each call to new_activity if any new object is created in my activity model. Also i need to pass the activity_id for the first time when  page is loaded.

I am not sure how to do that in my ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Save not activity_id, but latest_activity date in user browser. When ajax queried and there is an new activity, save new date of latest activity in user browser, and for next ajax query send that date, so server-side app will send only activity after that date.